# qTip2 - using included styles

Tags: jquery, qtip2

Apparently, I have difficulty following instructions.

Plugin: [qtip2](http://qtip2.com/guides)
Docs: [api - styles](http://qtip2.com/options#style)

qTip2 includes several built-in styles, but I cannot seem to access them. Everything I tried just results in the standard yellow tooltip.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/95V28/)

HTML:

```
<img id="bob" title="Bobbing for apples" src="http://placehold.it/30/30" />
<img id="frank" title="Let me be Frank with you" src="http://placehold.it/30/30" />
<img id="mary" title="He's getting Mary'd" src="http://placehold.it/30/30" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('[title!=""]').qtip({
    style: {
        classes: 'qtip-bootstrap'
    }
});
```

I also tried putting the `img` tags into DIVs - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95V28/2/) - but the results are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine but you have got the wrong css

I have updated the css url to

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.css
```

which includes all of the styles

Updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gsiry01/9wDar/1/

Comment: I didn't imagine my initial sentence would be so accurate... thanks tons for your help. I look forward to reviewing your other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Your Qtip CSS file is just include basic CSS as you can point out from the URL:

```
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.0/basic/jquery.qtip.css
```

which lack of some extras styles such as the custom color theme like what you're currently applying.

Since you're using `jsdelivr` CDN. You can use this link with full features CSS styles instead:

```
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.css
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95V28/3/)**

Comment: I didn't imagine my initial sentence would be so accurate... thanks tons for your help. I will review your other answers.